# Can't figure out how to inject assets using assets-webpack-plugin

Tags: caching, webpack, assets-webpack-plugin

Clearly I'm missing something here, I'm trying to prevent caching using `assets-webpack-plugin` but I seem to have trouble understanding their documentation Here's what I did:

**My Config**

```
...
import assetPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
...

...
output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.[hash].js'
    },
...

    plugins: [
        new assetPlugin(),
...
```

That successfully generates a file in my root called `webpack-assets.json` which contains:

```
{"main":{"js":"/bundle.dbe7d464b6bdec429d82.js"}}
```

In their [documentation](https://github.com/kossnocorp/assets-webpack-plugin) the only example they give on how to even generate anything in the HTML template looks like this:

```
new AssetsPlugin({includeManifest: 'manifest'})
// assets.json:
// {entries: {manifest: {js: `hashed_manifest.js`, text: 'function(modules)...'}}}
//
// Your html template:
// <script>
// {assets.entries.manifest.text}
// </script>
```

which I take it to mean, using my generated file: `{webpack-assets.main.js}`

So I add this in my HTML template:

```
 ...
<body>
  <div id="app" ></div>

  {webpack-assets.main.js}
 ...
```

I even tried with the commented out:

...

```
  // {webpack-assets.main.js}
 ...
```

Curly brackets don't get replaced with anything so the HTML page just looks like .

```
{webpack-assets.main.js}
```

Clearly I'm missing something here that documentation, I'm guessing, assumed I knew already or I completely missed the ball on this.